# How to access state in function which is in another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, state

today I’ve finished my first React App - Calculator.

I though it will be better to have App.js clean and place all of the logic functions in separated file Logic.js and also all of the design functions (changing output font size depending on length of number or button on click animations) in for example Effects.js.

Problem occured when i took functions ,placed them in new file  (of course exported them and also imported them in app.js).

Error says that
setNumber(method which i call when i want to work with state),

number.firstNumber (firstNumber state which holds first clicked number),

And every state which im calling in this file (functions or conditions) is not defined ,so it means this file has no access to App.js state. Is there any way I can keep these functions separated and don’t  have to rebuild whole app so I can achieve clean code ?

**App.js creating states with which I work in these functions**

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState({
firstNumber: "",
secondNumber: "",
operator: "",
result: "0",
displayed: "0",
cButton: "AC",
cButtonCheck: false,
numToReset: false,
sizeOfOutput: "1em",
isOrange: false
});
```

**Example of function in new file which gets error of setNumber is not defined**

```
function turnOnOrange(operator) {
if (number.isOrange === false)     {
  setNumber(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    isOrange: true,
    whichOrange: operator
  }));
  operator.className = "orangeActivated";
}
}
```

Thanks, link so you can see whole code

https://codesandbox.io/embed/youthful-platform-n6lvs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&codemirror=1

Answer (score 2):

You should return these variables from the function and export the function not vice versa.

What you're trying to do is called custom hooks I'll give you an example in which you can reflect on:

```
useMyFirstCustomHook.js file
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const useMyFirstCustomHook = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  // do some stuff
  return { count, setCount };
};

export default useMyFirstCustomHook;

App.js file
//..
import useMyFirstCustomHook from 'path/to/useMyFirstCustomHook';
//..
const { count, setCount } = useMyFirstCustomHook();
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can define your own hooks to manage partial state since Hook was born to share state. Here is one of example:

yourHook.js

```js
export function colorHook(initValue) {
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState(initValue);

  // Define whatever you want
  const setOrange = () => setColor({ isYellow: true }) 

  return [color, setColor, setOrange, // pass more ];
}
```

In your main file:

```js
import { colorHook } from "./yourHook";

function yourComponent() {
  const [color, setColor, setOrange] = colorHook({ /* your value */ }) 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split the single state object you have in the `App.js` into multiple manageable cohesive states and then make your own **custom hooks** which would manipulate a part of the state you have just split.

For example for the `turnOnOrange` function, you can create new hook called `useOrangeHook` in its own file and import and use it as a hook:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function useOrangeHook(operator) {
  const [orangeState, setOrangeState] = useState({
    isOrange: false,
    whichOrange: ""
  });
  if (!orangeState.isOrange) {
    setOrangeState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      isOrange: true,
      whichOrange: operator
    }));
    operator.className = "orangeActivated";
  }
  return orangeState;
}
```

Custom Hooks are a mechanism to reuse stateful logic. Check out the React guide [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html).

Comment: Great answer to this question, this is a really good way to do what you're looking for @Pinnci

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So ,if i get it right ,I have to remove all states from app.js , create them and work with them in another file which i’ll export?  (for this example isOrange and whichOrange) will be removed from App.js and created in new file just like you showed me in your answer? @Fullstack Guy

Comment: @Pinnci Yes you need to split your single state object in App.js into logical cohesive states to be managed by your custom hooks.

Comment: But there is a problem . Almost every function links to another function. I mean ,for example turnOnOrange(operator) is called inside operator(e) function ,which is called when + - / * is clicked . So i dont understand this concept ,how i should separate these states so i still be able to call functions inside of functions and so..For example that passed value ‘operator’ from operator function to turnOnOrange is that specific button which I’ve clicked. Sorry but i’m new to React and dont really understand more complicated things like this one yet.

Answer (score 0):

First off, separating things makes a lot of sense, except when you're trying to manage state of a component. The reasoning here is that the state is wholly managed by the component including the lense variables, in your case `[number, setNumber]`. Having a function that calls these externally from the component raises a big red flag and as you've noticed does not work.

The reason it's not working is a matter of scope. The function `turnOnOrange` will not be called within the scope of the component itself. As you're using a function component, `this` has very little meaning so even a `turnOnOrange.call(this, operator)` isn't going to be much help.

So, whilst I applaud you for wanting to separate out your logic, in this case it is working against you and actually isn't very intuitive if you think about it. Your function `turnOnOrange` absolutely belongs inside that component.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I though about it same way as you because every function which i want to separate from main file is using states in conditions ,so as you sad,that functions just belongs there. I was just wondering about making final version nice,clean and readable and this problem occured.

Comment: Well, another answer here has a really nice solution for you using custom hooks, check it out https://stackoverflow.com/a/63218230/1010632 from @FullstackGuy